# ASP.NET MVC updates in partial views with a different model to the main view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC and I'm having some teething trouble.  I'm working on a project where I have a couple of tables - Firm and User.  Each Firm can have multiple Users.  I have created a registration View which effectively merges the fields of both into a single View.  I also have a separate View for editing Users, and another for creating Users within an existing Firm.  It makes sense to me to use a partial View so I only need to update the UI in one place.  However, I am hitting a bit of a problem.  When I use the partial in Create/Edit, it works fine as I just use it as

```
@Html.Partial("UserDetails",Model)
```

However, when I use it within Register, I try to do

```
@Html.Partial("UserDetails",Model.AutoFirstUser)
```

AutoFirstUser is a property that I created that automatically creates a user if none exists, otherwise it just returns the first user in the firm.  This seemed like the easiest way to merge the data into a single View.  Thinking about it now, I realise that I could just use User as the model and use User.Firm for the other fields, but that would just shift the problem to the FirmDetails Partial View instead.

Anyway, the problem that I am finding is that although the fields for the user are visible and validate properly, when I post the form back, they are not finding their way back into the model, presumably because the models are effectively in different "namespaces" as the Partial View expects the main Model to be a User and the Register View expects it to be a Firm.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Partials were not what I wanted - I have solved this with Editor Templates